# How to set reply timeout in TcpOutboundGateway to infinity

Tags: spring-integration

Incase of MessageTimeoutException, the connection is closed. I don't want to close the connection incase of MessageTimeoutException as I need to send retry messages through the same outbound channel.
To keep this connection alive, I want to set the timeout to infinity. I tried `clientFactory.setSoTimeout(-1)`, but it didn't work. Even I tried `gateway.setRemoteTimeout(-1)` as well.

Could you please help, how can I set the timeout to infinity?

I have set gateway.setRequestTimeout(10000) and for timeout I get MessageTimeoutException with text as

`"Timed out waiting for response"` error, where as I should get `"Timed out waiting for connection".` Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the remote timeout to `Long.MAX_VALUE` which is effectively infinity. This will wait forever (unless you set the socket timeout on the connection factory). I would not advise doing that; choose a more reasonable timeout.

> as I need to send retry messages through the same outbound channel

You can't do that; we have to close the socket because we lose any way to correlate the responses - we might get a response for the first message after you send the second. Once we time out, that socket has to be considered "dirty" so we close it.

The gateway is **Strictly** for request/response messaging. If you want to use arbitrary peer-to-peer messaging you need to use a pair of channel adapters instead.

Comment: I added "You can set the remote timeout to `Long.MAX_VALUE` which is effectively infinity.".

Comment: Thanks Gary for the help.